How to change WooCommerce "Pay For Order" button text
I've added a code snippet to the child theme functions.php page to change the "Pay For Order" button on the checkout page to read "Pay Now". The text hasn't changed. What am I missing?
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_button_text', 'wc_custom_order_button_text' ); 

function wc_custom_order_button_text() {
    return __( 'Pay Now', 'woocommerce' ); 
}


Would need additional information. Are you trying to change the cart page or checkout? Both? Could be an issue with the theme you are using etc.

It seem that you are using newly checkout Block, that doesn't allow this kind of customization. The hook woocommerce_order_button_text only works in classic checkout (shortcode).

I'm trying to change the button on the checkout/order-pay/ page.

Could you please try to give a try to woocommerce_pay_order_button_text which allows the text of the submit button on the Pay for Order page to be changed.
add_filter( 'woocommerce_pay_order_button_text', 'wc_custom_pay_order_button_custom_text' ); 

function wc_custom_pay_order_button_custom_text() {
    return __( 'Pay Now', 'woocommerce' ); 
}

